# How to replace Suspend with Hibernate on a laptop with kubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, suspend, laptop, power-management

I dont have any option for hybernation. `sudo pm-hibernate` works so its a supported function. How to do it when my lid is closing instead of Suspending?

Comment: I'm amazed `sudo pm-hybernate` works since it's mis-spelled... are you sure you don't mean hibernate? ;)

Comment: Sorry, typo. Any ideas?

Comment: no need to be sorry, just trying to help you make your question clearer. Sadly I can't help with this - I don't have Kubuntu & hibernating causes my kernel to panic so I can't test!

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: 16.04 different kernel and some old workarounds doesn't work.